# How to output an empty file with gulp if stream is empty

Tags: gulp

When I use `gulp-concat` in my Gulp task, no files are written if the stream is empty (glob pattern does not match any file). How can I write a Gulp task in such a way that there is always one file written to the destination (consisting of concatenated input), even when there are no input files?

Comment: How about creating a new task for the non-matching pattern and pipe an empty string?

Comment: Are you trying to always have a destination file from gulp-concat even if it is empty? Do you have a sample use case for this behaviour?

Comment: @clapas I was thing about that, but how can I append an empty string to the stream?